# android.app.ActionBar class not being recognized

Tags: android, api, android-manifest, android-studio, android-support-library

The problem i'm facing right now is Android Studio doesn't recognize import classes api level 11 and above. And in manifest the minsdk version i'm using is 14, this is fustrating. I'm trying to import android.app.ActionBar but i can't, i was going to use support library but there's no sense if i'm using api level 14.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it modyfing the build.gradle in the section {android,defaultConfig} :-)